# Is there any library to convert SCSS string to CSS string?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

I would like a JS library (can run on Browser) to convert this SCSS string:

```scss
{
  .person {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
   
    &__name {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

to this CSS string:

```css
{
  .person {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
   
  .person__name {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Does that exist?

Comment: That's... literally the whole point of SCSS, so: "yes". Go find a Sass converter that will run client-side, by starting at https://sass-lang.com/ and then doing some websearching based on the terms that teaches you are associated with sass and scss (which is a file extension, not actually the name of the code you're showing)

Comment: "*I want a JS library…*" requests for off–site resources are off–topic here.

Comment: @RobG I saw many people answering questions by linking to off-site resources so I think there is nothing wrong with my question.

Comment: Linking to information elsewhere as part of a question, comment or answer (e.g. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript), [ecma-international.org](http://ecma-international.org)) is fine, however a question requesting off–site resources isn't.

Comment: @Kahnh, have you checked [medialize/sass.js](https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/)? never used myself though. and remember RobG is correct in regard for off-site resources.

Comment: If the question is "how do I convert an SCSS string into a CSS string via JS" then, the request for an off-site resource is simply a means to an end...

Answer (score 1):

You can you ¸use node-sass (Syntactically Awesome Style Sheets)

Here's to code that your may want to use :

```
    const sass = require('node-sass');
    
    const scssString = `
    {
      .person {
         font-size: 1.2rem;
   
         &__name {
            color: red;
         }
      }
    }
    `;
    
    const cssString = sass.renderSync({
      data: scssString,
    }).css.toString();
    
    console.log(cssString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use official SASS JavaScript API:
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api/